# Unable to make pendrive bootable using UNetbootin

Tags: unetbootin

I was trying to make pendrive bootable using UNetbootbin but was getting following message. I am very confused that why I am getting so. Please help me to solve the issue.
[http://oi59.tinypic.com/352lrty.jpg].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pendrive is no longer mounted.

Unplug the drive and plug it back in to mount the device.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the ISO downloaded, you can try using "dd" instead.

Open up a terminal and type

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdc
```

Comment: you can also use `cat` (which is sometimes faster than `dd`)

Comment: except you have to run it as root `cat /path/to/iso > /dev/sdc`